# Conflicto de arrays String de Objeto

Tags: java, array

Tengo un problema con mi programa, y es que estoy modificando un arrayString de uno de mis objetos(uso posicionamiento por que es un array de objetos y cada objeto tiene un array String inicializado con espacio " ").
Lo que pretendo hacer es, poner un valor en alguna posicion del arrayString obtenido(a un auxiliar->salaReg=sala[0].getReg()) se supone está vacios, pongo el valor en salaReg[cualquier posicion]=id <- es string y luego hago un seteo
sala[0].setReg(salaReg)

Se supone que aqui sólo he modificado el arrayString del objeto sala[0] y se supone que el resto de objetos sala[desde el 1 hasta el ultimo] siguen con un arrayString vacio.Pues segun mi programa no es así, y pues cada vez que se modifica un arrayString, se modifica en todos. por lo que suelta un desbordamiento por que el arrayString tiene 7 posiciones y las salas tienen 10.

public class Visitante extends Thread {

```
private Semaphore sem;
private String id;
private Room sala[];

public Visitante(String id, Room sala[], Semaphore sem) {
    this.id = id;
    this.sala = sala;
    this.sem = sem;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    String salaReg[];
    String salaRegAnt[];
    boolean listo = true;
    boolean existe = true;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;
    int numRan;

    try {

        sem.acquire();
        System.out.println("/////////////////HILO " + id);
        System.out.println("Estoy en sala " + sala[0].getId());
        salaReg = sala[0].getReg();
        System.out.println("Actual");
        for (int m = 0; m < salaReg.length; m++) {
            System.out.printf(salaReg[m] + " | ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
        //System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
        while (listo) {
            if (salaReg[j].equals(" ")) {
                salaReg[j] = id;
                sala[0].setReg(salaReg);
                listo = false;
            } else {
                j++;
            }
        }
        j = 0;
        listo = true;
        numRan = (int) (Math.random() * 2000 + 400);
        Thread.sleep(numRan);

        System.out.println("Museo con " + sala.length + " salas");

        //Empieza desde la posicion 1 ya que la posicion 0 la usé anteriormente
        for (int i = 1; i < sala.length; i++) {
            salaReg = null;
            System.out.println("Soy " + id + "  y estoy en sala " + sala[i].getId());

            salaReg = sala[i].getReg();//Array que se supone que debería estar vacio
            //ya que a cada sala del array de salas
            //se le ha "seteado" un array de tipo String
            //con tamaño 7
            //e inicializada a " "

            salaRegAnt = sala[i - 1].getReg();//este array del anterior objeto(por eso i-1)
            //debería tener 1 sólo dato

            System.out.println("Actual");
            for (int m = 0; m < salaReg.length; m++) {
                System.out.printf(salaReg[m] + " | ");
            }
            System.out.println();

            while (listo) {
                if (salaReg[j].equals(" ")) {//EL PROBLEMA LO DA AQUÍ
                    salaReg[j] = id;
                    sala[i].setReg(salaReg);
                    System.out.println("Antes");
                    for (int m = 0; m < salaRegAnt.length; m++) {
                        System.out.printf(salaRegAnt[m] + " | ");
                    }
                    System.out.println();

                    while (existe) {
                        if (salaRegAnt[k].equals(id)) {
                            salaRegAnt[k] = " ";
                            sala[i - 1].setReg(salaRegAnt);
                            System.out.println("Despues");
                            for (int m = 0; m < salaRegAnt.length; m++) {
                                System.out.printf(salaRegAnt[m] + " | ");
                            }
                            System.out.println();
                            existe = false;
                        } else {
                            k++;
                        }
                    }
                    listo = false;
                } else {
                    j++;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
            j = 0;
            k = 0;
            listo = true;
            numRan = (int) (Math.random() * 2000 + 800);
            Thread.sleep(numRan);
            System.out.println("///////////////////////////////////////");
        }
        sem.release();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Clase sala

public class Room {

```
private String id;
private String reg[];

public Room(String id, String reg[]) {
    this.id = id;
    this.reg = reg;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public String []getReg() {
    return reg;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public void setReg(String reg[]) {
    this.reg = reg;
}
```

}

Clase Principal

public class Principal {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int ROOMS = 10;
    final int VIS = 7;
    final int GROUP = 7;
    Semaphore SEM = new Semaphore(1);

    String reg[] = new String[GROUP];
    Room sala[] = new Room[ROOMS];
    Visitante hiloVisitador[] = new Visitante[VIS];

    //Inicializa reg
    for (int i = 0; i < GROUP; i++) {
        reg[i] = " ";
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < ROOMS; i++) {
        sala[i] = new Room(String.valueOf(i + 1), reg);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < VIS; i++) {
        hiloVisitador[i] = new Visitante(String.valueOf(i + 1), sala, SEM);
        hiloVisitador[i].start();
    }
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < VIS; i++) {
            hiloVisitador[i].join();
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

}

Os dejo mi codigo para que lo lanzeis y observeis mi problema

Comment: Parece ser que el arreglo es compartido por las diferentes instancias de tu programa.

Comment: somo lo puedo solucionar? es que quiero que cuando acceda a una instancia ( sala[1], sala[2]...etc cualquiera) sólo modifique el array que hay en esa instancia y no la del resto. :/ llevo desde el viernes noche y apenas he dormido xD hasta pesadillas me da xD no sé como solucionar eso :/

Comment: Investigando un poco, he dado con algo que puede que me ayude, intentaré usar un ArrayList, y asi evito que se comparta el array en la instancia. Analizandolo a fondo funcionaría y solucionaría mi problema, lo implantaré e informaré si logré solucionarlo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema está aquí:

```
sala[i] = new Room(String.valueOf(i + 1), reg);
```

Todos los objetos en `sala` usan el mismo arreglo `reg` en el parámetro. Por ende, al cambiar el estado en `sala[0]` se ve "afectado" en los demás elementos de `sala`. El "afectado" va en comillas puesto que ese es el comportamiento normal de los objetos.

Lo que necesitas es tener un arreglo diferente para cada instancia de `sala`. Te recomiendo que reorganices el código así:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ROOMS; i++) {
    String reg[] = new String[GROUP];
    for (int i = 0; i < GROUP; i++) {
        reg[i] = " ";
    }
    sala[i] = new Room(String.valueOf(i + 1), reg);
}
```

Según tu último comentario, un `List<String>` podría solucionarlo, siempre y cuando se asigne una lista diferente a cada instancia de `sala`.

Comment: He mezclado tu solucion con el array list y esta todo perfecto, muchas gracias!